# Cross domain webmethod call using jquery

Tags: jquery, .net

I have a webmethod hosted on domain A inside a .aspx page. I need to call this method from domain B. I am using `$getJSON()` to make this call, but when it comes back `data.query.results[0]` is always null.

Jquery code in domain B.

```
// Accepts a url and a callback function to run.
function requestCrossDomain() {
    var site = 'http://domain A/Services/A.aspx/GetString'; 
    var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=json&callback=?';

    $.getJSON(yql, cbFunc);

    function cbFunc(data) {
        if (data.query.results[0]) {
            var result = JSON.parse(data.results[0]);
            alert(result);
        }
        else 
            throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
    }
}
```

Domain A Webmethod

```
<WebMethod()> 
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True)>
Public Shared Function GetString() As String
    Dim ResultString As String = New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("Test Result")
    Return ResultString
End Function
```

The above method works absolutely fine when I call the method from the same domain. But cross domain call always returns null.

When I checked in Fiddler, there is track that says the server responded and the content length is 616. But the result I get back is null.

Response Headers

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Cache-Control: private
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Encoding: gzip
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcQ29tbW9uXFBST1xIUk9cU2VydmljZXNcSFJPQ29yZS5hc3B4?=
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Mon, 05 Dec 2011 15:07:54 GMT
>   Content-Length: 616

I am not sure what I am missing. I've tried using `JSONP` and `$getJSON`. Both doesn't return any value.

Please let me know if you require any further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I see two problems with the script.  First, you should create the `cbFunc` before passing it into the `getJSON`.  Secondly lets check if yahoo is returning it's data by alerting when it was created.  If the results is empty you'll need help with the yahoo api more.

```
// Accepts a url and a callback function to run.
function requestCrossDomain() {
    function cbFunc(data) {
        if (data.query.created) {
            //var result = JSON.parse(data.results[0]);
            alert(data.query.created);//put a breakpoint here to check the data.results if you get it created.
        }
        else 
            throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
    }

    var site = 'http://domain A/Services/A.aspx/GetString'; 
    var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=json&callback=?';

    $.getJSON(yql, cbFunc);

}
```

Comment: Ok. But I think I got what I am missing. The domains that I specified are the hosted in my localhost in different ports. Domian A : localhost:12345 and domain B: loclahost:45612.And these applications are not hosted in web. There are only available in my local machine. They cannot be browsed through internet. Can you explain if that is the reason yahoo api is unable to post the script  tag in the page that I am requsting.